# Help completing proof. Calculating sum of series.

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve the ex 5.11 from "Probability Essentials", which asks to show that if X is Poisson(λ) then

{|−|}= $\frac{2\lambda^\lambda e^{-\lambda}}{(\lambda -1)!} $ .

I've shown that

{|−|} = ${2\lambda^\lambda e^{-\lambda}} $
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k\lambda^k}{(k+\lambda)!}\right) $
but I'm having trouble calculating the sum of this series:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k\lambda^k}{(k+\lambda)!}\right) $.

Could somebody help?

EDIT: This is what I have done

{|−|} = $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{|j-\lambda|\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) $

= $\sum_{j=0}^\lambda \left(\frac{(\lambda - j)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)$ + $\sum_{j=\lambda+1}^\infty \left(\frac{(j-\lambda)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) $

= $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(\lambda - j)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)$ - $\sum_{j=\lambda+1}^\infty \left(\frac{(\lambda-j)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) $ + $\sum_{j=\lambda+1}^\infty \left(\frac{(j-\lambda)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) $

= $2\sum_{j=\lambda+1}^\infty \left(\frac{(j-\lambda)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) $

= $2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k\lambda^{k+\lambda}e^{-\lambda}}{(k+\lambda)!}\right) $

= $2 e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k\lambda^{k}}{(k+\lambda)!}\right) $ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Hope the question is better phrased now.

Comment: Hint:split the integral by whether $X$ is better than $λ$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I show that

$$ \color{blue}{\mathbb {} |−|= \frac{2\lambda^{m+1} e^{-\lambda}}{m!} } $$

with $\color{blue}{m=\lfloor \lambda \rfloor},$ which is nothing but the median of Poisson  distribution. When $\lambda$ is integer, the formula given in the OP is obtained.

Unifying the summation makes the problem difficult. Instead, the following method works:

$$ \mathbb {} |−|= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{|j-\lambda|\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^m \left(\frac{(\lambda-j)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) +\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty \left(\frac{(j-\lambda)\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)= \\ \sum_{j=0}^m \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)-\sum_{j=1}^m \left(\frac{\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{(j-1)!}\right) +\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{(j-1)!}\right)-\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) = \\ \left [ \sum_{j=0}^m \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)-\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)} \right ] +\left [\color{blue}{\sum_{j=m}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right)}-\sum_{j=m+1}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda\lambda^je^{-\lambda}}{j!}\right) \right ]=\frac{2\lambda^{m+1} e^{-\lambda}}{m!}.$$